# Remove inner wall on thin shell model with complex geometry

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, topology, 3d-printing

Is there an easy way to remove the interior wall on a model with complex geometry? The model was imported from an STL file for a object which is very large, but has very thin walls. One of the walls needs to be selected, then deleted in the edit mode.

[image]

Note: Using the mesh selection tools requires a huge number of steps to separate the mesh.

Comment: Is the inner shell completely detached and independent from the outer wall?

Comment: The inner shell is fully attached to the outer shell by seams at the edges. The mesh mesh was imported in the single STL file.

Comment: Hum yeah I was thinking something along the lines of what Copperplate mentioned bellow in his answer, but it obviously wont work here. Could we perhaps have access to this STL file? maybe if you convert the topology to quads, then hide all the border loops between the inner and outer shell then you can easily select them apart.

Comment: Regarding the geometry shown on the screenshot it should be possible to use Select > Sharp Edges from the 3d viewport header, then in edge select mode hide the selection; thus edges connecting inner and outer parts will be hidden and you can use Ctrl+L on the inner part to select it. This might not work for all mesh parts if they differ from the shown one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the inner mesh is separate (but is one piece) you can use L or CTRL + L to select linked (sometimes selecting different options for this in the tools panel (such as Material or Seam) will also help in different situations. If it is separate pieces, you can either select some vertices in each piece and hit CTRL + L, or just hover over the individual pieces and press L. Please let me know if this helps at all.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your inner mesh have different Normals, try selecting one of them and go to Select > Select Similar > Normals

And then see if it selects them all